# Parse a jdouble* native variable to a double* native variable (jni)

Tags: java, c++, parsing, java-native-interface, double

I try to parse an array of double that I got from jni in a "jdouble*" variable.
What I want to do is convert that array of double to a "double*" array.

It doesn't work and gives me a result like :

> X0 875387640 875387816 959506832 875387864

Here is my code :

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_MainFrame_Jni_Functions_sendTablesToNative
(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jobject paramObj, jobject respObj, jobject objObj, jobject ConObj, jobject intConObj){

    jclass jTablObjClass = env->FindClass("MainFrame/Jni/TablesObjects");           // get jclass 


    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    jobject col, row;       // will be used to navigate within the jobjectarrays
    //************************************************************

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    jint     paramNbRows;       // will get the parameter nb rows

    jdouble* paramValue;        //
    jdouble* paramMin;          // Define double variables for
    jdouble* paramMax;          // param : value, min, max, reference
    jdouble* paramReference;    //

    col             = env->GetObjectArrayElement((jobjectArray)paramObj, 0);    
    vector<char*>   paramName(  env->GetArrayLength((jobjectArray)col)  );      // define parameter Name Column size

    col             = env->GetObjectArrayElement((jobjectArray)paramObj, 5);    
    vector<char*>   paramType(  env->GetArrayLength((jobjectArray)col)  );      // define parameter Type Column size

    //
    paramNbRows     = env->GetArrayLength((jobjectArray)col);                   // get parameter nb rows

    col             = env->GetObjectArrayElement((jobjectArray)paramObj, 1);
    paramValue      = env->GetDoubleArrayElements((jdoubleArray)col, 0);        // get parameter value column

    col             = env->GetObjectArrayElement((jobjectArray)paramObj, 2);
    paramMin        = env->GetDoubleArrayElements((jdoubleArray)col, 0);        // get parameter min column

    col             = env->GetObjectArrayElement((jobjectArray)paramObj, 3);
    paramMax        = env->GetDoubleArrayElements((jdoubleArray)col, 0);        // get parameter max column

    col             = env->GetObjectArrayElement((jobjectArray)paramObj, 4);
    paramReference  = env->GetDoubleArrayElements((jdoubleArray)col, 0);        // get parameter reference column

    col             = env->GetObjectArrayElement((jobjectArray)paramObj, 0);
    for(int i=0; i<(env->GetArrayLength((jobjectArray)col)); i++){ 
        paramName.at(i) =  (char*)env->GetStringUTFChars(
            (jstring)env->GetObjectArrayElement( (jobjectArray)col, i), 0 );    // get parameter name column
    }

    col             = env->GetObjectArrayElement((jobjectArray)paramObj, 5);
    for(int i=0; i<(env->GetArrayLength((jobjectArray)col)); i++){ 
        paramType.at(i) =  (char*)env->GetStringUTFChars(
            (jstring)env->GetObjectArrayElement( (jobjectArray)col, i), 0 );    // get parameter name column
    }
    //************************************************************


    printf("\n\n    %s %d %d %d %d %s", 
        paramName.at(0),        (double)paramValue[0],      (double)paramMin[0], 
        (double)paramMax[0],    (double)paramReference[0],  paramType.at(0)     );



    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////



    jstring str = env->NewStringUTF("Test Jni from C++");
    jmethodID printMethId = env->GetStaticMethodID(jTablObjClass, "print", "(Ljava/lang/String;)V");// get jmethod
    env->CallStaticVoidMethod(jTablObjClass, printMethId,str);                                      // call jmethod

    return; 
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starters: why all the casts?  If you're using the JNI interface
correctly, there should be no need for any casts.  If we take the first,
for example: if `paramObj` is declared to be an array in the native
interface, the type passed in should be `jobjectArray`, and not
`jobject`; if it declared to be an object, then calling
`GetObjectArrayElement` on it should not work.  (Since both `jobject`
and `jobjectArray` are probably typedef's to pointer types, and the
interface is `extern "C"`, with no type checking of arguments, you might
get away with it if the parameter on the Java side is actually an array
of objects.)  I'd recheck all of your types, if I were you.

As to the strange output: you're matching a `double` to a `"%d"` format 
specifier, which requires an `int`.  Undefined behavior.  Just drop
`printf`, and use `std::cout`, and the problem will solve itself
automatically.  (Otherwise, use `"%e"`, `"%f"` or `"%g"` as format
specifier.)

Comment: I tried it `cout << "line 0 : " << paramName.at(0)<< " "<< paramValue[0]<< " "<< paramMin[0]<< paramMax[0]<< " "<< paramReference[0]<< " "<< endl;` but I get  this output `line 0 : X0 2.3385e-057 2.33856e-0572.33862e-057 2.3385e-057` ... And I do send an array of java objects

Comment: @Kuroicloud666 Which displays the doubles as doubles.  If these aren't the doubles you expect, that's a different question (and I would start by fixing up all of the types, so that I don't need any casts).